# Does pg-native for nodejs work on Heroku postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I want to query Postgres database synchronously for my node.js app, for that I'm trying to use pg-native on localhost, but will it work on heroku when I deploy it?

Or should I also consider pg-sync?

Answer (score 0):

Yes pg-native will work on Heroku. I have a hobby-tier (free) app that uses the following modules:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "pg": "^8.6.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "pg-native": "^3.0.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.5"
  }
```

It uses sequelize to manage the database. pg-native is used when you call the constructor with the "native" attribute set to true.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
    process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    process.env.POSTGRES_PASS,
    {
        dialect:"postgres",
        host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
        port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
        // Native enables ssl which is req'ed by Heroku Postgres. Requires 'pg-native' npm package
        native:true,
    });
```